# Android NDK, How to add more native function to existing library?

Tags: android-ndk

Let' say I already compiled native source codes and got libNativeLib.so file. If I want to add more functions to the library then how do I do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you asking how to add them to an already compiled library?  If so, I would highly recommend against doing that.

Comment: ok..then what do I do? Do I create another library? But I already have Android.mk file in jni forder in the project directory..

Comment: Well, if you can modify the source code for the library, just do that, and re compile.  It sounds like you can do that as you're talking about your Android.mk file in your jni folder.  If that's not an option, then yes, make another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the header file(s) to `libNativeLib.so` You can rename it to `libNativeLibMid.so`, then You can write your `c` methods and compile this code into `libNativeLib.so` using static linking to `libNativeLibMid.so`.